# How to customize caption of the bxlsider

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I need to add the caption with in the image of slider and have to move each sliders,when clicked the respective captions.

I have added the  **captions: true** in javasript,but still the captions are outside the images.And I need to customize the captions and replace them as text for the sliders.I have attached a sample image below to explain what I need. I have attached my code as well.

What changes I have to do to my code to get captions like this.[image]

```
<ul class="bxslider">
<li><img src="http://bxslider.com/images/730_200/tree_root.jpg" /></li>
<li><img src="http://bxslider.com/images/730_200/hill_fence.jpg" /></li>
<li><img src="http://bxslider.com/images/730_200/trees.jpg" /></li>
</ul>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.bxslider').bxSlider();

    });

    $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
        mode: 'horizontal',
        infiniteLoop: true,
        auto: true,
        autoStart: true,
        autoDirection: 'next',
        autoHover: true,
        pause: 3000,
        autoControls: false,
        pager: true,
        pagerType: 'full',
        controls: true,
        captions: true,
        speed: 1200,
        slideWidth: 800
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Where is the caption supposed to be positioned? I don't see that in your example image. There's only numbered placeholders with one highlighted as active.

Comment: @temp read https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up and  https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer/  If the answer helped you could vote up at least, if not accept.

Answer (score 1):

You should add a `figure` tag with a `figcaption` within your `li` list items, but they work. (I suppose you could add a span either?.. just thought of that)

If you opt to use to add the span, you would need to add `display:block;` to the css.

The figcaption with the caption text should be contained within the figure tag. Span tags should be included BEFORE the end of the closing `</li>`

For example (I've used figcaption here)

```js
$('.bxslider').bxSlider({
  auto: true,
  autoControls: true
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.bxslider li img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 125px;
  margin: 0px 5px;
  padding: 10px 3px;
}

.bxslider {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.bxslider li {
  display: inline-block;
}

figcaption {
  padding: 0!important;
  margin: 0!important;
  color: #2F4F4F;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

figure:hover,
figcaption:hover {
  color: forestgreen;
  background-color: yellow;
}

figure:active,
figcaption:active {
  color: forestgreen;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://bxslider.com/lib/jquery.bxslider.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="http://bxslider.com/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://bxslider.com/lib/jquery.bxslider.js"></script>

<ul class="bxslider">
  <li>
    <figure><img src="http://www.rachelgallen.com/images/daisies.jpg" />
      <figcaption>Daisies</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </li>
  <li>
    <figure><img src="http://www.rachelgallen.com/images/snowdrops.jpg" />
      <figcaption>Snowdrops</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </li>
  <li>
    <figure><img src="http://www.rachelgallen.com/images/mountains.jpg" />
      <figcaption>Mountains</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </li>
  <li>
    <figure><img src="http://www.rachelgallen.com/images/yellowflowers.jpg" />
      <figcaption>Yellow Flowers</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </li>
</ul>
```

the background color/padding/margin sizes are  just for example, edit as you see fit..

Hope this helps

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/yuujw17b/)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/unez0voy/ yes, span works too, but you'd have to add display:block to the span css

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/vrhkh0qb/ was the original figure with just a hover change, no background color and not entirely enclosed within the <figure> tags which it should be ideally

Comment: Thank you for the answer.I got the idea. sorry for late reply